# Svelte 5 - change component on login

Tags: svelte, svelte-5

I am trying to change component once the user is logged in, but so far I am not able to do this. Once I make successful login, component remains the same.

[Link to the test repo](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/#H4sIAAAAAAAAA-1XW2_bNhT-K6w7zE4RWXE7p60SuwvSDdgwtMXS7WUeBlqiLbaSSJCULzP833cOqaste0E3YC_TgyXy3C8febzrLXjCdC_4bdfLaMp6Qe9Oyt5lz2wlLvSKJYbBWotchbhzq0PFpZnOsllG4OGpFMqQHVnQiJE9WSiRkr6T842imeaGi6x_wB3mSrHM3AvYyOCjkhz6K87WQ6dg-En3b9DSrd8weyunu0P5oWHaPBjFs-X-1pfAd-tUBGFlwsRcT44lK4b9FMwcCKGiiK8IjyazHnqG_s96pI4swMCnLjx0FLitl7MM0paKiC84i3qBUTnbX1ZZbgRZZ_uTbma6yNXPEBjNwZxxGZr1hn69V-iY9SBNhcBPYsmzKpt2VXC5XC7yLETHSagYNez-IB-Di51134Qi04b8YcRnlpEJ1DfRzFESZgjNTSwU_5NFQPsK3DFsUPC-IRgsCZzIRS1TlwJEIqb4ikWDJw1Nbwrng0bUDfm6xrXNtngfWfog38-Y_Sykq5hzGWHM7WDNzLTCQfed3My0bIJ6qiOql3RJ-0jfOzbFTK4yUuhattJTmajYapoj7C_dW7flMrb-lSY5q-VbTpbkto5lM83HpivSsVQd6LFYTWvLHWSzyoj9YRvbjq6NjvA-Odl-N-eRYzvki06oU2cOIqqBR4ulhuDjAdgQ-jsQIiu2NEspT-pu7mPDljRJtV4LFR2QawYsCybyKIUlk__sGXw8I99KqmhKdjsiFVsBy1u2oHliAjK4IJMpWQke3ZD9nlgiiviogOptFpIKOzqfp9wMLA-2CLGPXQ7bemsPiHVyeAS7klr46cPPgpkwHvRjY2Tg-4kIaRILbYLX4_HYp5LDFmSxf0l2DSF8UgawiADzH94_fOxfHlBjBuez0sGRGD79uzBk0vRBmEqZ8JBipP4nDTfWoSLLfy8yAwF4H6H7uqRuSBhTBUie_PLxe-_VkZL94cZcRNuA_Pjw_t1QW4TxxXbQ5artlC6fyjY5tHTR2Ggt8BmamGUDxbTE-uN7iO4PLroZkYaMXY7ZSj0YoeiSDSHyHwxLB313F0C1UHRoF3VbNsVtfzRvhhpbnRHtW9MAXs5lL4UJZAKuacUSKMiKkXTjwZEpyNpb5ElCUrrx1l4akfnSW8fcMCI33jWRxhtdETn3XhEd00isvU1CsBLeyL2Wim6911dX_pjoNFAizyIWIROsQMPoataz978dFEonnM2Cgk-LatjGeCHEy1SDxbLFozbXCzC0gK7zNEv5XCQRsdulUyD-wJcZ4ZCVeNRWJStNqfGeN-TGTTkyZ4lYE8gTBTBoTbZwkuI3BGrcLFXoK2abjnhA__gwkIVQKahBaAAHzExwEdgTBFY797U_kDnSW5fSeNcdzFaAZzI3XZTymfMsClZ4WU52Fkb7c9wyoSGLIdFMgQff2QP6LooAIxrCOCNYOi0ZU-jwqGy8OaCTKW8ONSg-bRVeXF1hB8LPFngbZgNbKTtiwsGNqFiIMNdBUxhKWOyK3CQ8Y14GADrvIIIBkQZ3BwM_391BUfzunCYUugIMYApsyoC1ik9wbFzPnvja2iV0rkWSA6SMkBBRwhYGXjCswJHt4Yq4eKCczINw_eduhLZNYsPVaaNBX0F0QtKQm633ctyYtj0K-YzgdLCLEbDBRMY8MAJpIJh5r5FIT8dinQXoE1o8RUazc1BzlqHKumVyqXfBNjZk0l6XkR1ulUFCS7ca7Na3iT8GRQt61e6XQYXg6IR1LC-OHsHZqr1j__DU6zNt1URXKXAOYG18fahNtvDzn4LoMaiQHY7_D4x_ERhlZ_wDTKTb01CY58bAUFNgwd1HjVoWXVfe9m5qmEMGPmO7vcB2-8bVxY0SRXMV08L1icaq72pn_rFBya7JoaM93MX-VmRfP908f3ljSEzhRKBZeZ2TLTNvOtNBSazYAgw8fXIS7aUPp8YRjDoWK8AeJk1h3KSjtqczc-rUyGWnzz6dDo8TKNtjiI9I6phhyi_3PvePsx5IH_e3E-0cDanT6-vrU6Z-3_8Fb2Ur-IgTAAA=)

I have **App.svelte** component:

```html
<script>

    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    import { currentComponent } from './store/view.svelte';

    const loadComponent = currentComponent()

    $effect(() => {
        console.log(loadComponent);
    })

</script>


<div id="viewport" transition:fade>
    <svelte:component this={loadComponent.component}></svelte:component>
</div>
```

**Login.svelte component**

```html
<script>
    import { currentComponent } from "../store/view.svelte";

    let email = $state('')
    let password = $state('')

    let test = currentComponent()

    /**
    * @param {{ preventDefault: () => void; }} event
    */
    async function submit(event){
        event.preventDefault()

        fetch('http://localhost:9555/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(json => {
                localStorage.setItem('_token', json.token)

                test.updateComponent()
            })
    }
</script>
<div
        class="relative mx-auto w-full max-w-md bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:rounded-xl sm:px-10">
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-900">Sign in</h1>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Sign in below to access your account</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5">
            <form action="" onsubmit="{submit}">
                <div class="relative mt-6">
                    <input
                            bind:value={email}
                            placeholder="Email Address"
                            class="peer mt-1 w-full border-b-2 border-gray-300 px-0 py-1 placeholder:text-transparent focus:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none"
                            autocomplete="NA" />
                    <label for="email" class="pointer-events-none absolute top-0 left-0 origin-left -translate-y-1/2 transform text-sm text-gray-800 opacity-75 transition-all duration-100 ease-in-out peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:text-base peer-placeholder-shown:text-gray-500 peer-focus:top-0 peer-focus:pl-0 peer-focus:text-sm peer-focus:text-gray-800">Email Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="relative mt-6">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                            bind:value={password}
                            placeholder="Password" class="peer peer mt-1 w-full border-b-2 border-gray-300 px-0 py-1 placeholder:text-transparent focus:border-gray-500 focus:outline-none" />
                    <label for="password" class="pointer-events-none absolute top-0 left-0 origin-left -translate-y-1/2 transform text-sm text-gray-800 opacity-75 transition-all duration-100 ease-in-out peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:text-base peer-placeholder-shown:text-gray-500 peer-focus:top-0 peer-focus:pl-0 peer-focus:text-sm peer-focus:text-gray-800">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="my-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full rounded-md bg-black px-3 py-4 text-white focus:bg-gray-600 focus:outline-none">Sign in</button>
                </div>
                <p class="text-center text-sm text-gray-500">Don&#x27;t have an account yet?
                    <a href="#!"
                        class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:underline focus:text-gray-800 focus:outline-none">Sign
                        up
                    </a>.
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**view.svelte.js**:

```js
import Restaurant from "../routes/Restaurant.svelte";
import Login from '../routes/Login.svelte';

export function currentComponent(){

    const _token = localStorage.getItem('_token')

    let authorized = $state(_token ? true : false)

    let component = $derived(!authorized ? Login : Restaurant)

    function updateComponent(){
        authorized = true
    }

    return {
        get authorized(){
            return authorized
        },
        set authorized(newValue){
            authorized = newValue
        },
        get component(){
            return component
        },
        updateComponent
    }

}
```

Once I update **authorized** (test.updateComponent() call), the component is updated in **view.svelte.js** but the new component is not rendered. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the same instance, hence nothing happens.

You could e.g. do either of

- Make `currentComponent` a singleton, e.g.

  ```js
  function createCurrentComponent() {
    // [old code]
  }

  export const currentComponent = createCurrentComponent();
  ```

  (Of course you then would not call `currentComponent` any more.)
- Create one instance at the root component and pass that around, e.g. via [a context](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext).

Also, for the fade to work, you would need something like this:

```html
<div class="stack">
    {#key loadComponent.component}
        <div id="viewport" transition:fade>
            <svelte:component this={loadComponent.component} />
        </div>
    {/key}
</div>

<style>
    .stack { display: grid }
    .stack > * { grid-area: 1 / 1 }
</style>
```

Comment: Making a singleton doesn't work -  I am getting error **this={...} of <svelte:component> should specify a Svelte component.**
I made an edit - added link to the repo.

Comment: There is still a `currentComponent()` call in `Login` which breaks everything. This works just fine.